# Egit transport error while connecting to eclipse source code

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

I have been trying for couple days to download eclipse source code.  Always showing the following error message.

[image]

I followed the following step.

1. Installed Egit plugin
2. Configured Git and added username and password.
3. SSH2 generated RSA key and gave passwphrase and clicked the button Save Private key.
4. copied the sample eclipse source code url of eclipse jface I tried with ssh also.

git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jface/org.eclipse.jface.snippets.git

3. Pasted the repository url to Git repositoy view.
4. It automatically populated wizard with the values. And the protocol is git. clicked next. showing the same error message.

5 I tried with ssh protocol as well.There it was asking port number,username and password. what should I give there?
  filled username as anonymous and password left as empty.. and also tried with the username and password of git configuration.
   still the same error message.

I am using windows 8 64 bit.
jdk7.
eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like to be an old URL. Nowadays, you can find all the Eclipse Git repositories here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/

The JFace snippets are in the eclipse.platform.ui repository, see bottom of the following page for the Git URLs:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/

They are in examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets as [documented on the Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets).